# CUDA matrixMultiplyCUBLAS example error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED

Tags: cublas

Hello I have installed cuda 8.0 and I have compiled the cuda examples given.

I have tried to run the matrixMulCUBLAS example but I get the following error.

```
./matrixMulCUBLAS
[Matrix Multiply CUBLAS] - Starting...
GPU Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti" with compute capability 6.1

MatrixA(640,480), MatrixB(480,320), MatrixC(640,320)
CUDA error at matrixMulCUBLAS.cpp:277 code=1(CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED) "cublasCreate(&handle)"
```

I have also made this forum post on nvidias forums but they can't seem to figure it out for now.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1007071/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-error-when-running-matrixmulcublas-sample-ubuntu-16-04/

All other cuda examples work UNLESS they use CUBLAS for some reason.

Comment: You are absolutely certain that there is only one CUBLAS vesrion installed and that it is the version which ships 8 in CUDA? I don't really see any programming question here and don't think this is really an on-topic question for [SO]. If you have already contact NVIDIA on their forums, you have already done what it necessary.

Comment: How would I check which version of CUBLAS I have? It's possible that I might have more than one I guess but I should only have the one with cuda 8.0 installed.

Comment: The filename should tell you. Just as importantly check that you really only have one set of cublas libraries.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is that you have a readonly $HOME and CUDA JIT writes to $HOME by default. You can have a try with:

CUDA_CACHE_PATH=a_writable_path ...cmd...